# java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE074 no Code attribute specified;class=javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet, method=<init>()V, pc=0

Tags: jsf, maven, servlets, jsf-2, weblogic11g

I am using JSF 2.0 with Primefaces 3.4.2, Hibernate 4 Final and Spring 3.

When I am deploying an application to Weblogic 10.3.6 using Maven 3 I am getting the following excpetions. How can I resolve this issue?

Any help is highly appreciable.

```
Target state: deploy failed on Server mgdserver
java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE074 no Code attribute specified; class=javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet, method=<init>()V, pc=0
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBu
ilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBu
ilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter
.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Comment: Indicates that your build references code constructs that don't have the actual code in them. [This article](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract-in-class-file/) gives further direction. Ultimately, you'll need to install the proper JavaEE SDK

Comment: @kolossus I am deploying to our Weblogic Apps Server and it is using IBM JDK 1.7. Does that cause any issues?

Comment: @kolossus When I changed from `<scope>compile</scope>` to `<scope>provided</scope>` then problem resolved and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811674/error-while-deployment-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-ejb-hiber) issue occured.

Comment: @kolossus if I would want to use javee for 5 which version of JavaEE SDK should I download?

Comment: I don't think JavaEE 5 is still supported. [Use 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-downloads-439814.html) instead. But it seems you've resolved the issue with the compile directive anyway

Comment: @kolossus If you post as an answer I will be glad to accept it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I can't take credit for the `<compile/>` directive fix. That was all you man :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception when I tried to run unit tests, the solution for me was to exclude javaee-api from dependencies:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <classpathDependencyExcludes>
            <classpathDependencyExclude>javax:javaee-api</classpathDependencyExclude>
          </classpathDependencyExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly related to JSF, but what worked for me was to move the              javax.javaee-api dependency below the container implementation dependency.

Comment: In the maven POM? I doubt that was the real solution. Might be that changing this forced maven to reload things. But this being the answer to the problem in the question is difficult to understand or believe