# Error while deployment java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa-2.0, weblogic11g

I am Hibernate 4 Final and Spring 3.

When I am deploying an application to Weblogic 10.3.6 using Maven 3 I am getting the following excpetions although I have included `hibernate-entitymanager` in pom

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
          http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSF library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Primefaces library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>redmond</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oracle Java Connector library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-extcdi-core-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>       
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javaee</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
            <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- source output directory -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin> 
      <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId> 
      <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
      <version>10.3.6.0</version> 
      <configuration> 
          <adminurl>t3://myserver:7001</adminurl>
          <user>user</user> 
          <password>welcome1</password> 
          <upload>true</upload> 
          <action>deploy</action> 
          <remote>true</remote> 
          <verbose>true</verbose> 
<source>/apps.war</source> 
         <name>apps</name> 
         <targets>mytarget</targets>
      </configuration> 
      <!-- 
      <executions> 
         <execution> 
            <phase>install</phase> 
              <goals> 
                <goal>deploy</goal> 
              </goals> 
         </execution> 
       </executions>-->
       </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    <finalName>apps</finalName> 
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work JPA 2.0 and Hibernate properly apart from enabling JPA 2.0 in Weblogic 10.3.6 as mentioned in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13720/using_toplink.htm#autoId2) document, we need to have the following in Weblogic.xml

```
 <container-descriptor>
   <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
 </container-descriptor>
```

By including the above in Weblogic.xml solved the issue. More details can be found from 
**Oracle Support - JPA2 On Weblogic 10.3.5.0 using Hibernate implementation**
[Note 1487264.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?_afrLoop=1064956855274807&id=1487264.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=ydkuuzdzb_69)